# Cross Site Scripting issue with document.write

Tags: javascript, xss

I am working with some old code which has been reported is vulnerable to cross site scripting. The line of code is

```
document.write("<input type=hidden name=field1 value='" + getCookieValue('fieldval') + "' />");
```

The report also gave the following example on how malicious code can be injected into the page. By updating the cookie value as

```
fieldval='><img src=x onerror=alert(1)>
```

Can anybody provide insights on how this vulnerability can be fixed?

Comment: not sure if this is the issue but, you need to scape the quotes and double quotes.

Comment: How would anybody inject malicious code into your cookies? Of course, escaping it wouldn't be bad.

Comment: @Bergi I imagine the user just edited the cookies in the browser. I'm not sure how this would affect other users though, so I don't see it posing too much problem in the grand scheme of things. However, whatever coding practices lead to this XSS, are likely present elsewhere as well.

Comment: @Louis: Every user can execute malicious code on his own machine. So as long as one cannot influence the cookies sent to other users, this is not a security issue.

Comment: @Bergi correct, I indicated as much. However, the poor practices that lead to this issue are likely present in other parts of the code. Parts that may affect other users.

Comment: Cookies are HTTP headers, so with a little more work than with GET parameters, anybody can inject malicious code into cookie values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to validate the data coming from getCookieValue. If you're expecting a number, ensure that the value returned is numeric. Also ensure that any escape characters (e.g. quotes that break out of your javascript) are not present in the field. A fix for this would look like:

```
function is_valid(value) {
     // Do some check here depending on what you're expecting.
     // I also recommend escaping any quotes (i.e. " becomes \")
     // Ideally, you'd just whitelist what is acceptable input (A-Z0-9 or whatever,
     // and return false from this function if something else is present in 
     // value!)
}

var cookie_value = getCookieValue('fieldval');

if(is_valid(cookie_value)) {
    document.write('<input type="hidden name="field1" value="' + cookie_value + '" />');
}
```

Long story short, sanitize the data before you document.write or you end up with a reflected XSS.

As mentioned in the comments above, an XSS originating from a user's own cookies (something they modify themselves) is not particularly worrisome. However, whatever coding practices lead to this are likely present elsewhere. I'd recommend reviewing your source and ensuring that **all** input from users is treated as untrusted and sanitized appropriately.

Comment: I will try this, and respond back. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

Your code contains two mistakes:

1. You insert untrusted data into the output without encoding it correctly (which opens the door for reflected XSS attacks)
2. You use `document.write` to insert plain HTML into the DOM (which opens the door for DOM XSS attacks)

Before reinventing the wheel you should check out the OWASP cheat sheets to correct the mistakes:

1. [OWASP XSS Prevention Cheak Sheet - Rule 2](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.232_-_Attribute_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Common_Attributes)
2. [OWASP DOM based XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet - Rule 2](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.232_-_JavaScript_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Attribute_Subcontext_within_the_Execution_Context)

As you can see, your problem is not fixed by only escaping the quotes. Whitelisting your untrusted data is always the preferred way and a valid advice. For further reading about XSS in general the links contain many references.